# ObservableList: how to reliably detect a setAll?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, observablelist

In some contexts it's necessary to detect - in a ListChangeListener, without control about the list itself - a "all data swapped out", f.i. when we need to clear some state like selection - on completely new data the old state is meaningless.

Completely new data can be reached by

- list.setAll(...)
- list.set(otherObservableList)  if list is a ListProperty

Thinking about which type of changes could be fired on setAll (c is the change, items is the observed list, "subChangeCount" pseudo-code for counting the subchanges):

```
// initially empty
assertEquals(0, items.size());
items.setAll(1, 2, 4);
assertEquals(1, c.subChangeCount());
assertTrue(c.wasAdded() && !c.wasReplaced());
assertEquals(0, c.getFrom());
assertEquals(c.getList().size(), c.getAddedSize()); 

// initially not empty
assertTrue(items.size() > 0);
items.setAll(1, 2, 4);
assertEquals(1, c.subChangeCount());
assertTrue(c.wasReplaced());
assertEquals(0, c.getFrom());
assertEquals(c.getList().size(), c.getAddedSize());
```

This seems to allow a utility check like:

```
boolean wasSetOrClearedAll(Change c) {
   if (c.getList().isEmpty()) return true;
   c.next();
   if (c.getAddedSize() == c.getList().size()) return true; 
   return false; 
}
```

In contrast, internal fx code, f.i. in listening to ComboBox' items:

```
while (c.next()) {
   comboBox.wasSetAllCalled = comboBox.previousItemCount == c.getRemovedSize();
   ... 
}
comboBox.previousItemCount = getItemCount();
```

stores the old itemCount and compare that against the current removedSize (which I'm uncomfortable with, old state gets stale far too often for my taste), nevertheless there's a good probability that I'm missing something with my approach.

Question is:

in which context would my utility method fail (and core approach would detect the setAll correctly)?

Comment: What is the concrete type of the ObservableList you are using?  Looks like ListProperty is an abstract class that does not declare setAll(...)

Comment: @zeki hmm .. all ObservableLists must have a setAll(T... item) - can be unsupported, of course, so take any that has it implemented (ListProperty is nothing special, it simply routes the setAll of its backing list)

Comment: In that case, could you extend ListProperty and have setAll trigger an event before calling the super method?

Comment: @Zeki hmm .. looks like my question isn't overly clear (will try to reword it tomorrow :-) - my perspective if from the listener, just seeing the changes without any control over the sender.

Comment: @downvoter - care to explain?

Comment: @kleopatra:I don't understand your question. Especially assertEquals(0, c.getFrom());? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @kleopatra:Why not clear the delete/list?

Comment: @Phpdna I'm the listener - don't want to change the list itself, just do something if all content was swapped out. As to the c.getFrom(): a setAll fires a replaced starting at 0

Comment: @kleopatra:IMO the core code is safer. It guarantees the list is the same. Or can you use the core code and your solution parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no reliable way of detecting this on the Listener side.

The struggle starts with the default implemention, which mostly looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean setAll(Collection<? extends E> col) {
    beginChange();
    try {
        clear();
        addAll(col);
    } finally {
        endChange();
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you pass an empty Collection to `setAll` the result and the event that is fired are both exactly the same as when you would have called `clear`.

So your method `wasSetOrClearedAll` returns `true` when `clear` has been called, too (as would the core implementation).

So in the end there is no generic detection of `setAll`, it all depends on your use-case. If you can narrow down what you are trying to detect you may write a filter for that.

Comment: ahhh ... didn't even think at looking into core implementation ;-) Good argument, thanks! clear/setAll being the same is good enough -
 basically I need some means to reliably throw away all state
 related to old items (without having references to the items,
 only to their former positions). hmm ... back to thinking

Comment: And ListChangeListener.Change.getRemoved() / getFrom() / getTo() is not good enough for cleaning up?

Comment: hmm .. not if I follow core implementations of selectionModels. Which are buggy as hell, though. Probably need to think from scratch, maybe setAll is not such a special case, after all :-)